# How to echo a variable which is sent by php form

Tags: php, mysql, html, forms, submit

I have php form which get variable from other page. the code is given below:

```
<?php
    $fname = "$_POST[fname]";
    $lname = "$_POST[lname]";
//these value getting from another form
?>
<form action="test.php" method="post" class="form-inline vh_pre_reg_form">
<!-- Now I want to send them by this form-->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>First Name</label>
                <span><?php echo $fname; ?></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Last Name</label>
                <span><?php echo $lname; ?></span>
            </div>
<input name="submit" id="btnValidate" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

I want, when I will press submit button, these will go on action page ***test.php*** and on ***test.php*** page, my value will echo or insert it on ***mysql database*** but I can not echo or insert to mysql query them on ***test.php*** my ***test.php*** page code is given below:

```
<?php
if(count($_POST)>0) {

    /* Validation to check if Terms and Conditions are accepted */
    if(!isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $message = "<h1>404 error !</h1><br /> <h2>Page not found !</h2>";
    }

    if(!isset($message)) {
        echo "I got submit butt press";
        echo "<br />";
        echo "here is the value : ".$_POST['$fname'];
    }
}
?>
```

Please solve my problem, if possible, give me full code..

Comment: But there is no field for f_name and l_name in form...;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

store it into hidden element before `submit` button in your form like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="fname" value="<?php echo $fname; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="lname" value="<?php echo $lname; ?>" />
<input name="submit" id="btnValidate" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
```

And in your `test.php` file echoing it.

```
echo $_POST['fname'];   // name of the hidden input element
echo $_POST['lname'];   // name of the hidden input element
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not be encapsulating your variables in strings, use an array accessor on the super global `$_POST`. You should also use ternary assignment to check if the variable is set, so that your next question isn't about `undefined index` errors.

```
$fname = isset($_POST["fname"]) ? $_POST["fname"] : false;
$lname = isset($_POST["lname"]) ? $_POST["lname"] : false;
```

Next, don't check if the count of post is greater than zero, instead check that your form variables are posted.

```
if(isset($fname, $lname)){
    echo $fname . ' - ' . $lname;
}
```

Note that you also had `$_POST['$fname']` which is also not the correct way to access it.